# Is there an event which tracks the TranslateX value of a Xamarin Forms flyout page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail, flyout

I have a Flyout/Detail setup on my app with a hamburger button to trigger the flyout page.

I would like the hamburger to rotate at a rate proportional to the rate the flyout emerges from the left hand side of the screen.

I assume I'm looking for a change in `X` or `TranslationX`, but I can't find an event which tracks the changes in these properties.

I've tried catching it in `OnPropertyChanged` but it is not fired as the flyout moves.

Any ideas?

Comment: Per [TranslationX Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.translationx?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-visualelement-translationx), you can directly **gets** or **sets** the `X translation` delta of the `Flyout Page`. I don't think there's an `event` to track the changes of it.

Comment: Hi Alexander, do you have any ideas of a workaround then so that I can achieve what I'm looking for? I have noticed some apps are able to coordinate the flyout movement and the hamburger rotation.

Comment: Hi jho, you might need [Animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/) to make hambuger rotate. For more details, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I know how to rotate the hamburger already. What I don't know is how to make its rotation proportional to the TranslationX value of the flyout.

Comment: Hi jho, if `OnPropertyChanged` doesn't fire when flyout moves as we need this to make its rotation proportional to the TranslationX value. I don't think there's way to achieve it.